# Xcode Trouble with Projects Inside Project

Tags: xcode

I am working as part of a group that has a large codebase that contains multiple projects. I am having trouble creating a project that focuses only on the code I am interested in.

I created a project and added the root folder to my project with folder references (since I need to respect the existing file structure). I set the compile source for my target to the file that contains my main(). When I build, I also get build results for every other project contained in the file structure. Is there some setting that tells Xcode to ignore these other projects? Am I going about things the wrong way? I'm using Xcode 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to XCode 4.2 and this problem went away. (Still accepting advice on project organization.)